# MongoDB сортировка по наибольшему совпадению полей

Tags: mongodb

При поиске через **OR** возможно ли отсортировать документы по наибольшему совпадению с полями? Допустим если ищем name: 'Vasya', surname: 'Ivanov', на первых местах должны быть записи где оба поля совпадают.

Comment: на англоязычном сайте есть похожий вопрос, может быть будет полезно [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552968/mongo-get-results-in-order-of-maximum-matches-of-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552968/mongo-get-results-in-order-of-maximum-matches-of-value)